# Full height stops at browser viewport

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a simple layout in HTML and CSS that got 100% fullscreen height where the two columns are at equal height no matter how much content there is in them.

Like it is now, the scrollable area stops at the height of the screen, not the page. Please help me to get this working. I have tried almost every tutorial I can find.

The markup.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div id="sidebar"></div>

<div id="content"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS-code.

```
html,body {

height: 100%;

}

#container {

width: 600px;
height: 100%;

background-color: black;

}

#sidebar {

float: left;

width: 200px;
height: 100%;

background-color: blue;

}

#content {

float: left;

width: 400px;
height: 100%;

background-color: red;

}
```

Comment: 100% height for a element means 100% of the viewport. If you want it to be more than the viewport, you must specify the height in pixels, or lose the height and have enough content. I'm not quite sure I understood the question, hence I'm only commenting here.

Comment: This is doing exactly as it's told. What is your desired outcome? :) http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Drcx8/1/

Comment: That does not work. See what happends when your text goes above the 100% mark. :) Min-height would work -- but then the column next to it would be different height again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it, they way you're implying in your code (via CSS only).  You could make your `#container` be the same size as say, `#content`, but not #sidebar.  you could put your styles on your container and because that will stretch with a `height: inherit` property.

Here are a few other examples you can try http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

Another option would be to do a javascript resize of `#sidebar` to match `#content`, if you're interested in that route.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I can come up with solving your problem with pure HTML\CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/Drcx8/3/

As TNC mentioned, if you want them to be exactly the same height, you would need to use JavaScript to calculate both elements height and apply the larger height to the lower height element.